# Why does a plane with an image texture show as black in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I created a plane and added a Diffuse Material with an image as the texture, and a single lamp above it, using all default settings otherwise. Strangely, the plane appears as black in Cycles. I can't figure out what I could have possibly done wrong.

Do I need to tweak something? (Or is it normal for Cycles to treat a Plane with an image as not being illuminated (if there are no other objects in the scene)?)[image]

Comment: You must be doing something wrong elsewhere then as that node setup is correct..

Comment: Are you using the Import Images as Planes addon? yes, you definitely need some lights (planes with emitter material, with face normal pointing at the object to illuminate)

Comment: @zeffii no, I'm not.

Comment: @RolandiXor The Import Images as Planes addon, also created the UV data and makes a plane with the correct dimensions, it's worth using at least once so you know how easy it can be done.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add some Texture Coordinates! Generated works out of the box, and UV is even better. All pretty standard stuff. :)

[image: Cycles Material with an Image texture and Texture Coordinate attached]

Comment: This is most likely the solution. The Image Texture node uses UV coordinates by default, so they must either be created, or Generated texture coordinates must be used.

Comment: That was the answer for me and the "Texture Coordinates" is in the "Input " Add Nodes menu, took me ages to find that.

Answer (score 2):

This might sound obvious, but make sure you plug it to the "surface" input of the output node. Sometimes when you are trying out materials it moves the noodle to the "volume" input, that doesn't really work by the time and will give you completely black objects.

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar problems before when the lamp was in a different layer and in the my scene render layers the light's layer was not active.

So make sure that all the 3d layers that you want to see/contribute in the render are activated in the Render context Layers panel.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same Problem Turns out all I had to do was " DELETE " All the Suns,SpotLights,etc.. and presto image showed up!!

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1 : Don't Use Black Image .

Solution 2 : Select your plane and press tab( edit mode) , Press U Select Unwrap .

Answer (score -4):

You have to add a *BSDF diffuse* node between the nodes to tell blender the texture will be used for diffuse texture.